# Automatic Provisioning vs Ad-Hoc Provisioning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I would like to have 2 users test an iPhone app I'm working on.

What is the difference between copying it over to their devices by using the Xcode Organizer and pressing "use this device for development" vs giving them an ad hoc cert and the binary then having them sync it over iTunes?

The former seems easier to me and less error prone, but are there any negative consequences?

I've reviewed this article from apple, but it doesn't seem to answer my question:
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, and those are pretty much the same things - this information will be saved in their profiles on Xcode. In both cases you will still be subjected to the 100 device limit.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, for someone you can NOT get their iOS devices connected to your Mac, the AdHoc way is the only way you can share your binary.